# How to read a file which is having delimiter in the field values enclosed with double quotes in AbInitio

Tags: ab-initio

I have a .dat file which is delimited by a pipe (|). Now my columns can have | in the data. I am facing issues while reading this file and loading it column by column.

DML used:

```
record
string("|") col1,
string("|") col2,
string("|") col3,
string("|") col4,
end
```

Source value:

```
"Col1"|"col2"|"col3"|"col4"
"units of the price | currency used" | "ABC" | "20210831" | ""
```

So col1 =  units of the price | currency used, col2 = ABC , col3 = 20210831 , col4 = null

As per my dml it is breaking first col in 2 and hence failing.
How can I read the file and load it with the correct values.

Comment: Perhaps you could define the delimiter as string(\"|"\") i.e. use "|" as the delimiter instead of only | - you will end up with an extra " at the beginning and end of the record, but that is easily removed later

Answer (score 0):

You could define the delimiter as `string(\"|"\")` i.e. use `"|"` as the delimiter instead of only `|` - you will end up with an extra `"` at the beginning and end of the record, but that is easily removed later

Answer (score -1):

Please use "READ SEPARATED VALUES" component to achieve this.